# How to send a _search query to each elasticsearch routing/shard

Tags: elasticsearch

We have elasticsearch version 1.x and 2.x on different environments. On all documents we use custom routing. Only on one of the environments the routing is set to be required, so I cannot send a _search request without a routing param. We have total of 64 shards.

Now I have to delete all the documents of given type containing a specific field (index/**type**/id) on that environment. The way I planned to do that is to send a query to get all documents of the given type and then a bulk request to delete them. Unfortunately with the forced routing I'm not able to retrieve the documents with a single _search, as it must always include the routing.

Is there a way to iterate all possible shards and get all the documents (with some filtering), so I can bulk delete them after? I'm able to list all the shards with _cat/shards, but I did not find in ES docs anything that specifies how to iterate each shard without knowing the routing beforehand.

If you ask why I just don't use all routing values that I have - well they are billions of them - which hashed resolve to a 64 shards, so I don't think it's reasonable.

I'm not using delete by query, as in 2.x version of ES it's moved to a plugin and the ops team is not installing any plugin at this time.